# How fix Error: expected false to equal true html

Tags: javascript, html

I am learning the basics of HTML. I have the following code:

```js
alert(document.querySelector('div:nth-child(1)').childNodes[0].textContent.trim().length > 0)
```

```html
<div>
    <label>Name</label><br/>
    <input type="text"><br/>
    <label>Password</label><br/>
    <input type="password">
</div>
<div>
    <input name="gender " type="radio">
    <label>Male</label>
    <input name="gender " type="radio">
    <label>Female</label>
    <input name="gender " type="radio">
    <label>Others</label>
</div>
<div>
    <input name="answer" type="checkbox">
    <label>Answer 1</label>
    <input name="answer" type="checkbox">
    <label>Answer 2</label>
    <input name="answer" type="checkbox">
    <label>Answer 3</label>
    <input name="answer" type="checkbox">
    <label>Answer 4</label>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</div>
```

I expected the result to be `true`, since the first element of the first `<div>` is a `<label>`, which contains a string of non-zero length. The actual result is `false`, however. Why?

Answer (score 2):

You are using [`childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes), which retrieves **all** children, including text:

> `childNodes` includes *all* child nodes—including non-element nodes like text and comment nodes. To get a collection of only elements, use [`Element.children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/children) instead.

Thus, `document.querySelector('div:nth-child(1)').childNodes[0]` gives you the text that is between the `<div>` and the `<label>`, which stripped has no length. Instead, you should use [`children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/children), which gets the child *elements*.

For example:

```js
alert(document.querySelector('div:nth-child(1)').children[0].textContent.trim().length>0)
```

```html
<div>
    <label>Name</label><br/>
    <input type="text"><br/>
    <label>Password</label><br/>
    <input type="password">
</div>
<div>
    <input name="gender " type="radio">
    <label>Male</label>
    <input name="gender " type="radio">
    <label>Female</label>
    <input name="gender " type="radio">
    <label>Others</label>
</div>
<div>
    <input name="answer" type="checkbox">
    <label>Answer 1</label>
    <input name="answer" type="checkbox">
    <label>Answer 2</label>
    <input name="answer" type="checkbox">
    <label>Answer 3</label>
    <input name="answer" type="checkbox">
    <label>Answer 4</label>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When I used your code it seems that the spaces between `<div>` and `<label>Name</label><br/>` counts as text. Because of this `document.querySelector('div:nth-child(1)').childNodes[0].textContent.trim().length>0` checks the length of the space. Try and remove the spaces in the HTML and the error should disappear.

```js
var foo = document.querySelector('div:nth-child(1)').childNodes[0].textContent.trim().length > 0;
var bar= document.querySelector('div:nth-child(1)').childNodes[0];

console.log(foo);
console.log(bar);
```

```html
<div><label>Name</label><br/><input type="text"><br/><label>Password</label><br/><input type="password"></div>
<div>
    <input name="gender " type="radio">
    <label>Male</label>
    <input name="gender " type="radio">
    <label>Female</label>
    <input name="gender " type="radio">
    <label>Others</label>
</div>
<div>
    <input name="answer" type="checkbox">
    <label>Answer 1</label>
    <input name="answer" type="checkbox">
    <label>Answer 2</label>
    <input name="answer" type="checkbox">
    <label>Answer 3</label>
    <input name="answer" type="checkbox">
    <label>Answer 4</label>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</div>
```